# поиск неполных повторений pandas

Tags: python, pandas, дублирование

Есть датафрейм:

```
'AdGroupId';'CampaignId';'Id';'Keyword';'ServingStatus';'State';'Status';'StrategyPriority'
3767436593;42244009;16348493015;'фас тарифы;'ELIGIBLE';'ON';'ACCEPTED';'NORMAL'
3767436593;42244009;16348696779;'фас тарифы жкх';'ELIGIBLE';'ON';'ACCEPTED';'NORMAL'
3767470354;42244009;16348696813;'тариф тко;'ELIGIBLE';'ON';'ACCEPTED';'NORMAL'
1718324035;13004592;6511616422;'купить землю +под ижс;'ELIGIBLE';'ON';'ACCEPTED';'NORMAL'
1718324065;13004592;6511616584;'купить участок +под ижс;'ELIGIBLE';'SUSPENDED';'ACCEPTED';'NORMAL'
```

В нем необходимо найти такие значения 'Keyword' в которых есть повторяющиеся слова. При этом должны отличаться 'AdGroupId'. Т.е. значения первых двух строчек не должен вывести, последних двух строчек наоборот вывести

Comment: Что уже попробовали предпринять?

Comment: Если честно, то даже не знаю с какой стороны подступиться к данному вопросу. Может кто вектор задаст куда копать.

Comment: @Даниил Ермошин А начните-ка с изучения того, что такое Pandas  и того, какие возможности он предоставляет. А там глядишь, и вопрос задавать не придется. Но если при этом что-то конкретное на заладится -  задавайте вопрос. Поможем. А писать домашние задания  за того, кто даже не знает, как к задаче подступиться - как-то на этом ресурсе не принято.

Comment: Перечитал вопрос два раза, но так и не понял почему последние две строки нужно выводить, а остальные нет... Объясните как вы понимаете: `"такие значения 'Keyword' в которых есть повторяющиеся слова"`

Comment: первые два не должны попасть в финальный список так как у них одинаковый 'AdGroupId'. А у последних двух отличается и есть два повторяющихся слова купить и ижс.